# JQuery .load in jQuery loaded page/snippit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, load

I got this problem which I tried to fix already a couple of times, but without succes.

Here's what I got :

1/ when clicking on an item in page#1 I execute the following code :

```
$('.row').click(function() {
    $('#content').load('detail.php', function() {
        // some extra binding code
    });
});

detail.php is a PHP file with PHP code and HTML snippit (so no complete HTML page)
```

2/ This is a snippit of the content of detail.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#detail_content').load('subdetail.php');  <--- problem is here
    });
</script>
<section id='detail_content'>
</section>
```

This second load doesn't want to work. I found out why, but I don't understand why it won't work.
If I put an alert as first jQuery statement that check's if the element 'detail_content' exists, then it returns false. So this is the reason why the second load can't work. However, I don't understand why jQuery can't seem to find that element a that specific time ?
I am executing it in a $(document).ready(...) - block, so this code should only execute when the DOM is loaded, right ?

Anybody knows why this isn't working and how i can fix it ?

Tia !

Answer (score 1):

your DOM is ready after the page load is done. Loading a page via methods like *jQuery.load*, *jQuery.get* and so on won't trigger another DOM Ready event, as the DOM is only being manipulated (= new content is being inserted), but not re-generated (and thus the DOM stays ready throughout the whole AJAX load process).

A possible solution would be, to just execute your code within the callback of

```
    $('#detail_content').load('subdetail.php');
```

example code:

```
$('#detail_content').load('subdetail.php', function(){
    alert('page fetched!');
});
```

should work and an alert should be triggered as soon as your page is loaded.

greets,

Robin Heller

Comment: Hi Robin, I'm going to give you a +1 one, because using the callback is indeed a work around for the problem, however loading a page with load() triggers a $(document).ready(...) - event. I was able to identify the exact line of code that gives the problem. 
Instead of immediatly loading in the DOM tree, I load it in a new div and then append the result to the DOM tree. A that point the code can't find the object in the DOM so it fails. If I load it directly in an existing element, everything works fine, but then all the other content in that element is being removed, which I don't want either

Comment: Seems my rep isn't good enought yet, to upvote your solution :(

Comment: Hey, that's pretty strange - I could have sworn jQuery.load, which is wrapper to jQuery.get wouldn't produce another Document Ready event..thanks for the answer, though! If you plan on using jQuery more and more, you should propably get used to Callbacks, as you need them when you want to manipulate the data received in an AJAX call for example :)